# Define marriage in Hinduism

Tags: marriage

In short,  now a days marriage is defined as a **legal agreement**.

Is there any **explicit,  exact,  and precise** definition for marriage in Hinduism texts?

Comment: Im not asking for types of marriage which was answered already